# CakePHP - Tree recover() method returning an SQL error

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to do the recover() method on my Category model, I can use find(), etc. fine but whenever I try to call recover() to perform the lft and rght field updates, it errors with the below.

Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'recover' at line 1

Is this a bug or have I missed something obvious?

Controller:

```
class CategoryController extends AppController
{
    public function view()
    {

        // Errors
        $this->Category->recover();

                    // Works
        $this->set('category',
            $this->Category->find('first',
                array('conditions' => array('Category.id =' => $this->request->id))
            ));

    }
}
```

Model:

```
class Category extends AppModel {

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read the documentation
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html

As outlined you need to first tell your model that it is supposed to act as a tree (= to load the behavior):

```
class Category extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array('Tree');
}
```